# Getting EOF from known good csv file

Tags: csv, go

I have been writing a program to parse a csv file using the encoding/csv package. For some reason I have begul getting sporadic EOF errors. It is very strange since I am using the same file to test with over and over. Sometimes it parses fine. Other times it exits with an EOF.

This is a simplified version of the code:

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    LoadConfig()
    csvfile, err := os.Open(config.MonitorDir + "/test.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(2)
    }

    reader := csv.NewReader(csvfile)
    defer func() {
        csvfile.Close()
        MoveFile(csvfile)
    }()
    reader.Comma, _ = utf8.DecodeRuneInString(config.Delimiter)
    reader.LazyQuotes = true
    writeHeaders(reader)
}

func writeHeaders(reader *csv.Reader) {
  Headers, err := reader.Read() // This is where I see the EOF 
                                // (Headers = [] err = EOF)
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("Error is: %s\n", err.Error())
      os.Exit(2)
  }
  fmt.Println(Headers)
}

func MoveFile(file *os.File) {
    err := os.MkdirAll(Concat(config.MonitorDir, "/completed/"), os.ModeDir)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error is: %s\n", err.Error())
        os.Exit(2)
    }
    err = os.Rename(file.Name(), Concat(config.MonitorDir, "/completed/", filepath.Base(file.Name())))

    if err != nil {
        return
    }
}

func Concat(str ...string) string {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer

    for i := 0; i < len(str); i++ {
        buffer.WriteString(str[i])
    }
    return buffer.String()
}
```

**conf.go**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type Configuration struct {
    MonitorDir string
    LogPath    string
    Delimiter  string
}

var config Configuration

func LoadConfig() {
    file, _ := os.Open("conf.json")
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
    config = Configuration{}
    err := decoder.Decode(&config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error is: %s\n", err.Error())
        os.Exit(2)
    }
}
```

**test.csv**

```
Id,LastModified
"108420","2015-04-25T11:34:35.437332096-06:00"
"132774","2015-04-25T11:34:35.437332096-06:00"
"254790","2015-04-25T11:34:35.437332096-06:00"
"359972","2015-04-25T11:34:35.437332096-06:00"
"363060","2015-04-25T11:34:35.437332096-06:00"
```

This has become a blocking issue as it might throw 8, 10 or even more EOF before finally processing the file. I presume I am doing something strange to cause it. But, I cannot for the life of me see it.

Comment: You're expected to hit EOF eventually. At least with plain byte reads you often get data in the same `Read` call as the EOF, too. Does behavior look any better if you process any data you receive with the EOF?

Comment: (You can replace the `Concat` in `MoveFile` with regular string concats (`+`), right?)

Comment: @twotwotwo I actually do handle the EOF in the full version of the code. I exit on the EOF. What I am seeing is that it is exiting with an EOF on the very first reader.Read() where I get the headers. Oh, and yes I could use regular string concats. This function is actually just a helper I use in different places. Really didn't need it for this sample.

Comment: What is the operating system? I've tested it on mac os and it seems to work well with different CSV files, in parallel, etc. BTW, how does the EOF error look like in this case? On which line it happens and can you actually monitor the filesystem (like filemon on windows)?

Comment: Super weird. Don't have much in the way of ideas. A line-ending issue (file has Mac `\r` and Go wants `\n`) could make a file appear to have one line, but not zero. If in the real code something else read `csvfile` before you read the headers that could mess things up, but these are shots in the dark. (Does it happen running only the sample code?)

Comment: @AlexAtNet Well, I may have found the issue. I am on a mac as well. For some reason as I went to save the file in sublime text it saved it with Mac OS 9 line endings. When I switched it to windows or unix line endings it works fine. Need to do a bit more testing but, that seems like, at least a strong correlation.

Comment: @twotwotwo You are correct. I just got the error again even with the unix line endings. I did think about something else reading the file and ruled that out. Plus, it doesn't heppen every time. I would think it would in that case. I find it strange that re-saving the file caused it to start working pretty consistently. (I ran it in a loop 100 times and it didn't give me the EOF again until the 93 try.)

Comment: First, where are you encountering the EOF errors. Your error messages and exit codes do not distinguish the several places where you exit on error.

Second, I am suspicious of the defer'd function. You are using the Name() method after calling the Close() method. Even knowing what the code in the csv package did, I would hesitate to call any function on a file after closing it.

Comment: Thanks @DougHenderson I had actually thought of that as well and removed the MoveFile call from the defer. However, that did not change the result. I too was/am suspicious if the defer function. So, I added a log statement inside the defer function (just fmt.PrintLn("In defer...")) and it doesn't trigger. I will edit the post to better indicate where the EOF is thrown.

Comment: @DougHenderson I modified the sample code to better reflect the source code and added an inline comment where the actual EOF is encountered.

Comment: I created a test using the files you show above, with a hand crafted `conf.json` using the current directory (.) for the MonitorDir. I modified the error messages to be unique, and added error messages when os.MakeAll or os.Rename failed. I could not reproduce your problem. 
I am using `go version go1.4.2 windows/amd64`.

Comment: @DougHenderson I think I found the issue. That MonitorDir in the conf.json is truly a directory that is monitored. I am using fsnotify to watch the folder for new files then pass the new file onto this functionality. What appears to be happening is that the file occasionally gets to the read before the file in finished copying. I know, sounds unlikely. However, by adding a 1 second delay between receiving the event and passing it on, I have yet to see the EOF error again.